# How send get request to external api with username and password

Tags: rest-api, api

Actually i want to send get request to an api. the response is in xml.
I have tried this

```
<article>
    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php

        $url = "XXXXXXX";

        $args = array(
            'headers' => array(
                'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode( 'username:password' ),
                'Accept' => 'application/xml'
            )
        );

        $res = wp_remote_request(
            $url,
            array(
                'method'    => 'GET',
                'headers'   => $args
            )
        );

        print_r($res);
        ?>  
    </div>
</article>
```

I have tested the same url in postman and the response from server is coming. but in worpress, its not coming, its giving me 403 Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary data-protected error.

How to solve this please help me.

Comment: Hi! And welcome to the community! First of all, have you verified the encoded credentials are exactly equals? If you are debugging, you could show the encoded credentials first and the compare with the headers that postman is actually sending to the remote endpoint.

Comment: can you please help me how to compare the encoded credentials

Comment: yes i have checked the encoded creds both are same but its notworking

Answer (score 2):

Watch your keys:

```php
       $headers = array(
           // 'headers' => array( // this is duplicated
                'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode( 'username:password' ),
                'Accept' => 'application/xml'
           // )
        );

        $res = wp_remote_request(
            $url,
            array(
                'method'    => 'GET',
                'headers'   => $headers
            )
        );
```

Don't send `headers` inside `headers`. Using a variable name different from `args` can help you spot the issue.

Example reference in docs:

https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/http-api/#get-using-basic-authentication